# Reload file in vim

Tags: vim

When I have a file open in vim, in this case a log file, I'd like to trigger a refresh and load any file changes into my existing vim session.

I often use tail -f on log files, but as I'm using java and tomcat, the log messages are too much for tail...

Is there a vim command to reload an open file?

Comment: too much for tail? even as a vim user i dont see how vim can improve the situation ...

Comment: too much for tail in that the number of lines was unpredictable so I couldn't be sure that tail -f n 200 would be enough

Comment: I've a log generated by modsecurity that contains non-ASCII characters.  Both cat and tail lock the terminal when called on this file.  Vim merrily chugs along.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
:e
```

From `:h :e`:

> Edit the current file.  This is useful to re-edit the
>                           current file, when it has been changed outside of Vim.

Comment: thanks!  I thought at one point :e wasn't working for me but it works now!

Comment: or go to end of file as well...   `:e | $`

Answer (score 16):

While `:e` is the correct answer to the question you asked, if the goal is to tail a log with good scrollback, you can use less. `F` while viewing a file will scroll `F`orward, with continuous reloading. From the man page:

```
   F      Scroll  forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file
          is reached.  Normally this command would be used when already
          at the end of the file.  It is a way to monitor the tail of a
          file which is growing while it is being viewed.  (The  behav-
          ior is similar to the "tail -f" command.)
```

Less of an imposition on the user than rapidly `:e`ing in vim.

Comment: This is a better answer, IMHO. Though it technically doesn't answer the question asked, it's a better solution to his base problem.